# Work done by EMF in two wires system, in two different reference frames

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, work

EDIT:
I'm making progress in understanding in the discussion in the comments so take also a look there to have a complete picture. I also realized that the use of the "reaction force" words in the diagram below is wrong, it's actually an electric force.

I'm analysing the system of two current carrying wires one of which is moving with a velocity held constant by an external force. The system is pictured here:
[image]

The top wire is moving downward and vertically (in frictionless tracks) under the action of:

- the Lorentz force of the magnetic field generated by the down wire
- an external force maintaining the velocity constant
- the electromotive force opposing the horizontal component of Lorentz force.

I understand that work done by the latter two are equal and opposite in sign.

Firstly a couple of questions about the correctness of diagram above:

1. I drew a vector representing the reaction force of Lorentz force on the down wire, is this correct?
2. It appears to me that this reaction force is doing negative work if the charge carriers are positive, so moving in opposite direction with respect to the the reaction force, and otherwise if the charge carriers are negative they are moving in the same direction of the force, so the reaction force is doing positive work. How is this possible?
3. If this reaction force is doing work (positive or negative), what other force is doing the opposite work that restore the net work done on the system to zero?

And now the question that in the beginning led me to think about this system. In this reference frame the top wire is moving so the battery powering it is doing work.
If I switch by a Lorentz transformation to the reference frame in which the top wire is still and the down wire is moving in this new frame is the battery of the down wire that is doing work. How is this possible? Shouldn't be work done by a battery independent of the reference frame? Or maybe not in special relativity?

I don't think that in the new reference frame charge distributions appearing due to Lorentz contractions should play any role because the charge carriers velocity of the down wire is perpendicular to the velocity of new reference frame so this wire should remain neutral.
Currents will change due to time dilation but the force diagram I made should remain valid if one switches the down and the top wire, but I could be wrong.

I'm not completely sure of any of the considerations I made above (there must be surely something wrong in my thinking) so any correction is welcomed.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145063/discussion-on-question-by-mattia-work-done-by-emf-in-two-wires-system-in-two-di); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.